# Using boolean operators in a "case... when" statement (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, boolean

I'm trying to write a method that takes the user's input and checks it for validity. It's in a "case...when" statement. This part checks that the user has entered a Y or N only.

```
when 3
    input = gets.chomp.to_s.downcase
    unless input (=="y") || (=="n")
        puts "That is not a valid choice. Please enter Y or N."
        get_input(text, 3)
    end
```

The compiler doesn't like my boolean statement and I'm not sure why. It tells me "syntax error, unexpected [x]" and points to various parts of the statement. Pretty much tearing my hair out here... am I doing something obvious wrong?

Comment: Try this: `unless ['y', 'n'].include?(input)`.

Comment: The syntax you want is `unless (input=='y' or input=='n')`

Comment: That's it. I knew it was something silly. Thanks Cary.

Comment: The solution that @depa suggested is more idiomatic ruby

Comment: One of the requirements for questions about code you wrote is you provide an example that is usable: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself." Saying "points to various parts of the statement" doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
unless ['y', 'n'].include?(input)
```

Comment: The best answer IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the language(s) you come from, you might find one of these different ways more appealing. You could write:

```
 unless input (=="y") || (=="n")
```

As:

```
if !input[/^[yn]$/]
    puts "That is not a valid choice. Please enter Y or N."
    get_input(text, 3)
end
```

Or:

```
unless input[/^[yn]$/]
  ...
end
```

Or:

```
unless (input == 'y' || input == 'n')
  ...
end
```

Or:

```
case input
when 'y', 'n'
  ...
else
  puts "That is not a valid choice. Please enter Y or N."
  get_input(text, 3)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I find the `unless` first does not read well.  Starting off with a negative would be fairly ok here but in more complicated conditionals it loses readability.

I personally prefer

```
$ if q !~ /[yn]/ # Does NOT match pattern
$   puts "That is not a valid choice. Please enter Y or N."
$   get_input(text, 3)    
$ end
```

for maximum easy readability by all.

Answer (score 0):

Besides getting the condition right, there seems to be a recursion in your method. I suspect your method looks like this:

```
def get_input(text, option)
  # ...
  case option
  when 1
    # ...
  when 2
    # ...
  when 3
    unless condition
      puts "That is not a valid choice. Please enter Y or N."
      get_input(text, 3) # <- recursion!
    end
  end
  # ...
end
```

It would be better to use a loop here. Something like this:

```
def get_input(text, option)
  # ...
  case option
  when 3
    loop do
      valid = case gets.chomp
              when /^(y|yes)$/i
                puts "positive input"
                true
              when /^(n|no)$/i
                puts "negative input"
                true
              else
                puts "That is not a valid choice. Please enter Y or N."
                false
              end
      break if valid
    end
  end
end
```

The input is checked with another `case` statement. If the input is valid (i.e. `y` or `n`), `true` is returned and `break` exits the loop, otherwise `false` is returned, `break` is not called and the loops starts over again.

BTW, `(y|yes)` matches `y` and `yes`, `(n|no)` matches `n` and `no`, `^...$` ensures that there's nothing before or after, and the `i` makes it case insensitive.

So `/^(n|no)$/i` matches `n`, `N`, `no`, `No`, `nO`, and `NO`.

Comment: [`/^no?$/i`](http://rubular.com/r/dzLWdu0UXR) would work as would [`/^y(es)?$/i`](http://rubular.com/r/ZP2i94P0ik). Using the non-capturing form (`(?:es)?`) is more proper, but wasted energy for this task.

Comment: Yes, but it would take me a second to understand what `/^no?$/` is actually matching. Using alternation makes the regex very explicit and allows to add other values easily, e.g. `/^(y|yes|ok)$/`